# .alias file type for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, alias, file-type

Does anyone know what a .alias is as far as file type option goes for Android Studio? The one I'm working with is coming up null because android studio associated as a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Resource files are sometimes placed in the wrong folder, and it can
>   lead to subtle bugs that are hard to understand. This check looks for
>   problems in this area, such as attempting to place a layout "alias"
>   file in a layout/ folder rather than the values/ folder where it
>   belongs.

As Per reference from [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) android documentation.

There is an earlier reference to the alias file as well, in the same documentation.  At any rate, I would suggest that you do refer to this documentation and any other official android documentation that you can find for simple tidbits such as the one requested here..

> When you generate a resource alias, the resource you are pointing to
>   must be of the same type as the alias

Effectively, this is stating that the alias is a pointer from one false location to a separate true location..

When using google to search for information, you can be more specific by using keywords "OR" and "AND" as well as quoting.
To find the above information, I searched google for:

> "android studio" AND "alias file"

which brought it to me as the third result.  Earlier results being references to stackoverflow - this question, specifically.

There seems to be some additional information available [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) and [here](http://tools.android.com/download/adt-21-preview) as well.